# How to architecture an app where many functionality classes want to have access to same class?

Tags: c#, architecture

I need an architectural advice.

I have two classes:

```
public class Shell
{
    public IPage CurrentPage { get; set; }

    public void ChangePage(IPage page)
    {
        CurrentPage = page;
    }
}

public class SomeFunctionallityClass 
{
    private readonly Shell _shell;

    private readonly IPage _somePage;
    public Model1(Shell shell, IPage page)
    {
        _shell = shell;
        _somePage = page;
    }

    public void MakeSomeCrazyStuff()
    {
        _shell.ChangePage(_somePage);
    }
}
```

In Shell class i have a CurrentPage property and this is the property which very many classes in the application want to have access to.

Right now i pass Shell object to the classes which need to change the page.

But what will be the best way to give access to the same class for many other classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your solution of passing the Shell class to each other class that requires it, is not too bad, especially if you do it via the constructor.

Sure, the most common ways to do this are using the Singleton or a class with static methods. But if you are honest, in this context both of them are nothing but masked global state.

The original purpose of the singleton is to make sure only one object of a class exists, not to make something easily accessible. However the latter is the most common reason why developers use it. Other people therefore call it the "King of Antipatterns" :)

To be honest, I use both the Singleton and static methods myself in some cases to make my life easier (in the short term). But I never feel good about it.

To summarize, as far as I know you have three basic options:

- Pass object in constructor
- Singleton
- Static methods

All of these have their pros and cons, but I consider the first solution the cleanest because it does not introduce global state.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your Shell static:

```
public static class Shell
{
   private static IPage CurrentPage { get; set; }

   public static void SetCurrentPage(IPage page)
   {
      CurrentPage = page;
   }
}

public class SomeOtherClass
{
   public vod ShowShellPropery()
   {
      MessageBox.Show(Shell.Property);
   } 
}
```

Also having a setter ChangePage, you should make your CurrentPage private. Otherwise, you have two ways of changing your current page: with the setter `ChangePage(page)`, and with `CurrentPage = page`, which is not good. Also I renamed your setter `ChangePage` to `SetCurrentPage`, so now it is clear that it is a setter

Answer (score 0):

You might want consider using Singleton design pattern:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Choose the one that fully answers your requirements.